Memcache PHP extension for PHP 8.3 on Windows
Is there Memcache extension for PHP 8.3.7? If someone can share a link to download Memcache dll extension?
I downloaded Memcache extension for PHP 8.3 from here https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/8.2/windows. Then I added in the ext directory on PHP and enabled in IIS (php.ini), but I can't see it in the result from phpinfo() function.

Did you install Memcached as well. The extension is only a conduit to the actual memcached cache

ALso what OS are you using? Did you install PHP manually, or did you use XAMPP or WAMPServer or one of the other easy installers

Restart IIS so it loads the updated INI?

@RiggsFolly There is already Memcached installation and it is running in the services. It is installed long time ago. Now I just downloaded dll extension and set it in the php.ini. I'm trying locally on Windows 10, but on the server it should run on Windows server 2022 Data Center

@AlexHowansky yes, IIS is restarted.
